SetWindowSubclass on Windows 10 Notepad
I've been trying to solve this little problem the whole day, and I can't figure out what's wrong. I suppose this is a simple problem for some. So I'm trying to Subclass Notepad with a procedure that will block a certain message from being handed to Notepad, in my example I used WM_MOUSELEAVE
Here's my take on this:
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

// Subclass procedure to block WM_MOUSELEAVE
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_MOUSELEAVE)
    {
        std::cout << "WM_MOUSELEAVE blocked!" << std::endl;
        return 0; // Block the message
    }

    // Pass all other messages to the default window procedure
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize common controls
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex = { sizeof(icex), ICC_WIN95_CLASSES };
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // Find the Notepad window by its class name and window name
    HWND hwndNotepad = FindWindow(L"Notepad", NULL);
    if (hwndNotepad == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Notepad window not found!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Subclass the Notepad window using SetWindowSubclass
    if (!SetWindowSubclass(hwndNotepad, SubclassProc, 1, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "Notpad HWND is " << hwndNotepad << std::endl;
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to subclass Notepad window! Error code: " << errorCode << std::endl;
        // std::cerr << "Failed to subclass Notepad window!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully subclassed Notepad. Blocking WM_MOUSELEAVE..." << std::endl;

    // Message loop to keep the program running
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


I get the message "Failed to subclass Notepad window!" with errorCode showing 0 so I have no way of knowing what's going on.
I'm on 64bit architecture both Notepad and my cpp program.
I tried with an empty LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc() that always return 0, but seems nothing is working, which make me think I've got the syntax wrong.

The code needs to be in the same process to use SetWindowSubclass "...Warning  You cannot use the subclassing helper functions to subclass a window across threads...."

I didn't pay attention to this important limitation. Hmm! I can see on the web that there is a way to run this in the same process and that's by using DLL injection? If yes I'll look into that.

Yup, Window Hook to inject the DLL and then you can subclass on one of the hooked messages that will ensure that SetWindowSubclass is called on the correct thread.
